# ccache fails with read only

Tags: android, ccache

im building android 10 on an ubuntu machine. the source is custom and not googles' specifically. the source is hard-coded for a prebuilt clang to use ccache. i have installed ccache and added to bashrc these variables:

_CCACHE_EXEC=/usr/bin/ccache

_CCACHE_EXEC -M 50G

export USE_CCACHE=1

chmod and chown the ~/.ccache has the same results during the build, the actual error is:

ccache: error: Failed to create directory /home/brandonabandon/.ccache/tmp: Read
-only file system.

i cannot contact the owner of the source. i have attempted disabling ccache which leads to errors further on due to recent hard-coded ccache commits. i could build fine before. ive been stumped for a week. any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks that you have your ccache on the same partition as your source code. soong sandboxing mechanism does not like it:( you have two options:

1. start to use another partition/drive for ccache
2. mount your current ccache to another partition (/mnt for example)

Here is a list of steps for the second option:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ccache
sudo mount --bind /home/<your_current_path>/ccache /mnt/ccache
```

and needed env:

```bash
export USE_CCACHE=1
export CCACHE_EXEC=/usr/bin/ccache
export CCACHE_DIR=/mnt/ccache
ccache -M 100G -F 0
```

Comment: the path was to ~/.ccache not (ccache). sourcing bash with the proper path along with your answer sorted it. thanks mate.

Comment: Thank you! That worked.  My path was similar to that of Vladim.

Comment: In addition: If you want to make it persistent across reboots add the following to your `/etc/fstab`: `/home/<your_current_path>/ccache /mnt/ccache none defaults,bind,users,noauto 0 0` and to automount on login add this into your `~/.profile`: `mount /mnt/ccache`.

Answer (score 0):

Improving the accepted answer here as I hit this the second time:
PS: I am running as root

```
mkdir /mnt/ccache
mount --bind ~/.ccache /mnt/ccache
```

and env variables are the same as above:

```
export USE_CCACHE=1
export CCACHE_EXEC=/usr/bin/ccache
export CCACHE_DIR=/mnt/ccache
ccache -M 100G -F 0
```

In addition, I suggest putting those in `.profile` file using following command:

```
echo -e "\nexport USE_CCACHE=1\nexport CCACHE_EXEC=/usr/bin/ccache\nexport CCACHE_DIR=/mnt/ccache\nccache -M 100G -F 0" >> ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Not what the OP was looking for, but: If someone ends up here looking for a similar *ccache error msg* issue with arch/manjaro using

```
sudo pamac build <thing>
```

Then instead do

```
pamac build <thing>
```

and then type in password when prompted.